# React Populate AutoComplete materialui from Fetch result

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui, react-state

Can someone help me with this? i have an empty  material's AutoComplete, and this is how i set it:

```
<Autocomplete id="standard-secondary" options={MuscleCategory} getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title} value={muscleGroup}
                                  renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label={t('muscolarGroupFieldLabel')} variant="outlined" />}
                                  onChange={(val) => {
                                    setMuscleGroup(val.target.value);
                                  }}
                                  style={{ width: 300 }}
```

and this is the state

```
const [muscleGroup, setMuscleGroup] = useState('');
const [MuscleCategory, setMuscleCategory] = useState(new Array());
```

the first is used to save the selected item, the second is for 'display' all the categories in the autocomplete.
i don't know how to fill the MuscleCategory needed to be showed in the autocomplete, i tried to use the setMuscleGroup in a function:

```
function populateMuscleCombo(){
        fetch(something, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
        })
        
        }).then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {
                setMuscleCategory(responseJson);
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
            });
    }
```

but i doesn't do nothing, and the PHP is correct.

Comment: `const [MuscleCategory, setMuscleCategory] = useState(new Array());` is bad way to initialize an array but not wrong, refer, https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#arrays and As I can read the code, you are passing the whole response object, to `AutoComplete options prop` please check the data structure you need to pass it to Autocomplete it may be expecting the array of strings, but you may be passing the whole array of objects received from the backend, you may need to extract what you need to pass. Can you please share the response and material UI API for `AutoComplete`

Comment: Use codesandbox to send the examples, it is hard to understand just by looking at the code without the full code or abstractions in place